# xte bash command from xautomation not working on debian

Tags: bash, debian, xte

I tried with multiple commands, from

```
xte 'key a'
```

to

```
xte 'keydown Control_L" "key Tab" "keyup Control_L"
```

for alt-tabbing, or

```
xte 'mousemove 100 100'
```

and nothing works; I just get a blank new line in bash.